# How to sort rows with condition using stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I study the stream API, I have this task. I need to sort the List  collection in the order of their length, if the lengths of several lines are the same, then sort them alphabetically.

My Code:

```
List<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(phones, "iPhone X", "Nokia 9", "Huawei Nexus 6P",
            "Samsung Galaxy S8", "LG G6", "Xiaomi MI6", "Sony Xperia Z5",
            "ASUS Zenfone 3", "Meizu Pro 6", "Heizu Pro 6",
            "Pixel 2");

phones.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I got this output:

```
Samsung Galaxy S8
Huawei Nexus 6P
Sony Xperia Z5
ASUS Zenfone 3
Meizu Pro 6 
Heizu Pro 6
Xiaomi MI6
iPhone X
Nokia 9
Pixel 2
LG G6
```

As you see the lines

```
 Sony Xperia Z5
 ASUS Zenfone 3
```

And lines:

```
    Meizu Pro 6 
    Heizu Pro 6
```

But my result have to be:

```
Samsung Galaxy S8
Huawei Nexus 6P
ASUS Zenfone 3
Sony Xperia Z5
Heizu Pro 6
Meizu Pro 6 
Xiaomi MI6
iPhone X
Nokia 9
Pixel 2
LG G6
```

How can I improve my code so that if the lengths are the same, then the sorting is alphabetical?

How can we do collect results in List >? Where `List <Pair <String, Long>` for example:

```
String a = Abcd;
list.add(new Pair(a, a.length));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) to your comparator chain to create a secondary sort order. It will be applied when primary sort is not enough:

```
phones.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed()
                        .thenComparing(Function.identity()))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Neat. Didn't know there is a built in comparator like that.

Comment: wouldn't `String::toString` instead of `String::compareTo` also work? (genuinely asking)

Comment: Or `Function.identity()`, not sure what is the best way to express it. Edited my answer to use `Function.identity()`.

Comment: `thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())` makes much more sense I believe

Comment: how can we do collect results in List <Pair <String, Long >>?

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed().thenComparing(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder())`

Answer (score 1):

```
phones.stream()
      .sorted((a,b) -> b.length()-a.length() == 0? a.compareTo(b) : b.length()-a.length())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Add little explanation it can be helpful.

Comment: could possibly be improved to `Comparator<String> comparator = (o1, o2) -> o2.length() == o1.length() ?
                o1.compareTo(o2) : Integer.compare(o2.length(), o1.length());`